# Debian 9 - sign_and_send_pubkey

Tags: debian, ssh, git, ssh-agent

I decided to start switching my machines over from Ubuntu to pure Debian but I'm currently stuck at a hurdle with configuring my git repositories related to ssh. I created a new key and added it to the remote server but whenever I attempt to pull a repository, I receive the error:

```
xxx@xxx:~/Documents/my-repo$ git pull
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My permissions all seem to be correct:

```
xxx@xxx:~$ ls -al .ssh
total 20
drwx------  2 xxx xxx 4096 Apr  4 12:50 .
-r--------  1 xxx xxx 3381 Apr  4 12:46 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 xxx xxx  740 Apr  4 12:46 id_rsa.pub
```

Also, the key is listed:

```
xxx@xxx:~$ ssh-add -l
4096 SHA256:my-hash my-comment (RSA)
```

However, if I do the following it works:

```
xxx@xxx:~/Documents/my-repo$ ssh-agent git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

I've found several articles with the same ssh error, but the resolutions in those articles have not helped (i.e. my permissions already seem to be correct, my key is added/recognized, etc). I've been at this off-and-on in my free time for several weeks and haven't been able to resolve.

Based on the suggestion in the comments, I ran the following:

```
xxx@xxx:~/Documents/my-repo$ GIT_TRACE=true git pull
12:46:02.190213 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'pull'
12:46:02.192426 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
12:46:02.192653 exec_cmd.c:116          trace: exec: 'git' 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
12:46:02.198382 git.c:371               trace: built-in: git 'fetch' '--update-head-ok'
12:46:02.200462 run-command.c:350       trace: run_command: 'ssh' 'git@gitlab.com' 'git-upload-pack '\''xxx/my-repo.git'\'''
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Followed by:

```
xxx@xxx:~/Documents/my-repo$ ssh -v git@gitlab.com git-upload-pack xxx/my-repo.git
OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6, OpenSSL 1.0.2r  26 Feb 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [35.231.145.151] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 535
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Execute `GIT_TRACE=true git pull` to see what SSH command it tries to run, then issue it yourself (with added `-v` options, if necessary) to debug the problem. Add all this info to your question if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added the output above.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350768/sign-and-send-pubkey-signing-failed-agent-refused-operation?rq=1: gnome-keyring does not support all key types. If `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` outputs `/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh` you use gnome-keyring. Disabling agent usage like `SSH_AUTH_SOCK= git pull` should work if your key isn't protected by a passphrase (which isn't recommended). You need to fix your desktop environment, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/1586835 may help with that.